# Choosing a drug for a patient ( according to contraindications)

Tags: excel, formula

[image: Appropriate Drug]

Can anyone please help me in choosing the suitable drug

the case:
patient A is suffering from

- hypertension & Kidney disease

Drugs:

- Classified according the medical use:

e.g., { class A } : For painkillers
but as you see class A contain 3 drugs , I want a formula which will choose the suitable drug ( number 3 ) and not 1 or 2 or any drug from other classifications.

I tried to use IF function after naming true , false cells

IF(OR(AND(hypertension=TRUE,D4=1),AND(kidneydisease=TRUE,C4=1),AND(liverdisease=TRUE,B4=1)),b5,b4)

I think this helps me to make sure that the drug is suitable , but if it isn't the one , how the formula should test the next one.

thank you.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-and-and-or-to-test-a-combination-of-conditions-e1ed88d7-1de3-4422-ae41-45291a69f9e1

Comment: You need to explain better the logic behind this. Why Drug 3 and not drug 4 or 5 if all of them have no contraindications for Hypertension and Kidney disease?

Comment: Medicines No. 4 and 5 are not included because they do not belong to the class of pain killers (another medical effect ), that is, they are not suitable as a substitute for drug No. 1.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it is apparent that only someone with the requisite clinical knowledge can determine the class of drugs to be considered; accordingly the suggestion below uses a dropdown in cell `I12` for the appropriately-qualified user to make this choice:
[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed conditional-formatting based solution]
As your version of Excel is unknown this proposal uses a helper column, coupled with conditional formatting (in order not to have an overly-long formula). The [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) in cells `K6:K10` is

```
--NOT(MMULT($G$6:$I$10,--$D$7:$D$9))*($J$6:$J$10=I12)
```

which returns either a 1 if the drug on that row is suitable, or a 0 otherwise.
Conditional formatting is then applied to the `F6:J10` range to highlight the suitable drug(s):
[image]
(to implement the conditional-formatting rule, on the *Home* tab of the ribbon, click on *Conditional Formatting* -> *New Rule*, and you will be presented with a window similar to the above (click on *Format* to define your highlight style))